# Which trac component to use when submitting tickets for object_recognition stack?

Tags: ros, object-recognition

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to submit feature requests for packages in stack object_recognition but cannot find any suitable component in https://code.ros.org/trac/wg-ros-pkg. Leaving it unspecified is not exactly what I want. Suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9357/which-trac-component-to-use-when-submitting-tickets-for-object_recognition-stack?/) by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 960 on 2011-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The component should be the stack name, `object_recognition`, but it is not currently defined.

Try creating it yourself. If you don't have permission, add that to your question (as a comment) and someone with admin authority can do it for you.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on 2011-03-13**:
Ticket has already found an owner and component is changed to object_recognition. Thanks.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-03-09**:
I've created object_recognition as a component.  If you opened a ticket it should get to the right place eventually.

**Comment by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on 2011-03-09**:
Yes, it's not defined. I followed your suggestion, opened a ticket and will see what happens and whether it's necessary to find someone taking care of it. Thanks.